# get manager for each user in SharePoint people picker field

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, peoplepicker

```js
var usr=$("textarea[title='People Picker']:first").val();
var array = usr.split(";");

$.each(array,function(i){
   
   currusr=array[i];
   getMngr()
   alert(managerName);
});

function getMngr()
{

  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
    async: false,
    AccountName: currusr,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    //alert(Status);
      $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Manager')").each(function() {
        managerName = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
      });
    }
  });

      
}
```

I'm trying to check if the manager of all the users within a people picker field is same or not.

This is working fine only for 1st user.

Comment: Why not change the getMgr function take the currusr as an argument and return the managername instead of using a global variable which will get overrided with each loop

Answer (score 0):

I modify the code as below for your reference:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("div[title='People Picker']:first > span").each(function(){
        var currusr=$(this).attr("title");
        var manager=getMngr(currusr);
        console.log(manager);
    });
});
function getMngr(currusr){
    var managerName="";
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
        async: false,
        AccountName: currusr,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //alert(Status);
            $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Manager')").each(function() {
                managerName = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
            });
        }
    });
    return managerName;
}
</script>
```

Comment: its giving me an error for 'Status' in completefunc: function (xData, Status)